# How to print text form a particular part of a string?

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to know how to get text form a particular part of a sentence this is what i mean. `Hello (new text).`, in the brackets it says `new text` and i want to find the text in the brackets and print only the text in the brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `(` and `)` surrounding the text, you can use [string.match](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.match):

```lua
str = "Hello (new text)"
print(str:match("%((.+)%)"))
```

`%((.+)%)")` is a pattern that captures every character between the `(` and `)`.

Resources:
[Lua 5.3 Reference Manual - 6.4.1 Patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1)

Comment: or in two steps using a the balanced pattern `str:match("%b()"):sub(2, -2)`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is just to cancel out the Hello in your string.

```lua
local msg = "Hello (obama)"
msg = msg:gsub("Hello %(", ""):gsub("%)", "")
```

If the first part of the string is dynamic and is not always hello you can try this:

```lua
local msg = "Bye (obama)"
local pattern = "%p.+%p"
print(({string.match(msg, pattern):gsub("%)", ""):gsub("%(", "")})[1])
```

This soloution may not be the best and most efficient but it certainly works. I hope it helped you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: this is a bit restricted and overcomplicated (especially the last line) . Also note that the parentheses around the table constructor are superfluous.btw, if you want to reduce multiple return values to the first one, simply put the function call in parentheses.  `function a() return "a", "b" end  print((a()))` prints `a`, while `print(a())` prints `a  b` There is no need to put it into a table and index the first element.

Comment: see https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4    _"Any expression enclosed in parentheses always results in only one value. Thus, (f(x,y,z)) is always a single value, even if f returns several values. (The value of (f(x,y,z)) is the first value returned by f or nil if f does not return any values.)"_